# Account creation/management system hanging with NodeJs+DiscordJs+mysql2-promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise, discord.js

I created a Discord Bot for account creation/modification, but when getting too many requests the system hangs and nothing related to mysql works. I don't know if it is because of my async function or if I did something wrong. Basically the bot has 4 functions: Creating an account, changing an account username, changing an account password and linking the discord id to an already existing account. Once I get more than like 10 requests the bot stops working on everything related to the code below. My ping command still works, but all the commands related to the account creation (that are using mysql2-promise) stop responding. Important to state that bot doesn't give any error.
Here's the Bot code:

```
const db = require('mysql2-promise')();
const crypto = require('crypto');

db.configure({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: ""
});

module.exports = {
    name: 'acc',
    description: "Used to manage accounts!",
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord){
        const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get('something');
        if(!guild) return message.author.send("Guild error!");
        let member = await guild.members.fetch(message.author.id);
        if(!member) return message.author.send("Member error!");
        let role = await member.roles.cache.has('something');
        if(!role) return message.author.send("You don't have access to this command :eyes:");
        if(!args[0]) return message.author.send("Needs extra arguments!");
        if(args[0] === 'create') {
            if(!args[1]) return message.author.send("Needs both username and password!");
            if(!args[2]) return message.author.send("Needs a password!");
            db.query(`SELECT * FROM account WHERE discordid = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
                if(err) throw err;

                let sql;

                if (rows.length < 1) {
                    var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(args[2]).digest('hex');
                    sql = `INSERT INTO account (username, password, discordid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`;
                    db.execute(sql, [args[1], hash, message.author.id]);
                    message.author.send("Created your account!");
                } else {
                    message.author.send("Can't create your account!");
                }
            });
        }
        if(args[0] === 'changeuser') {
            if(!args[1]) return message.author.send("Needs to know the new username!");
            db.query(`SELECT * FROM account WHERE discordid = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
                if(err) throw err;

                let sql;

                if (rows.length < 1) {                   
                    message.author.send("Can't find your account!");
                } else {
                    sql = `UPDATE account SET username = ? WHERE discordid = ?`;
                    db.execute(sql, [args[1], message.author.id]);
                    message.author.send("Changed your username!");
                }
            });
        }
        if(args[0] === 'changepass') {
            if(!args[1]) return message.author.send("Needs to know the new password!");
            db.query(`SELECT * FROM account WHERE discordid = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
                if(err) throw err;

                let sql;

                if (rows.length < 1) {                   
                    message.author.send("Can't find your account!");
                } else {
                    var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(args[1]).digest('hex');
                    sql = `UPDATE account SET password = ? WHERE discordid = ?`;
                    db.execute(sql, [hash, message.author.id]);
                    message.author.send("Changed your password!");
                }
            });
        }
        if(args[0] === 'link') {
            if(!args[1]) return message.author.send("Needs both username and password!");
            if(!args[2]) return message.author.send("Needs a password!");
            db.query(`SELECT * FROM account WHERE discordid = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
                if(err) throw err;

                let sql;

                if (rows.length < 1) {
                    sql = `SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = ? AND password = ?`;
                    var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(args[2]).digest('hex').toLowerCase();
                    
                    db.execute(`SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = '${args[1]}' AND password = '${hash}'`, (err, rows) => {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        let sql2;

                        if(rows.length < 1) {
                            message.author.send("Can't find that account to link...");
                        } else {
                            sql2 = `UPDATE account SET discordid = ? WHERE username = ?`;
                            db.execute(sql2, [message.author.id, args[1]], (err) => {
                                if(err) throw err;
                            });
                            message.author.send("Linked your account!");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    message.author.send("You already have an account :eyes:");
                }
            });
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Get rid of the callback functions and use `async` functions with `await`. A database layer like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) uses Promises and makes this super easy. If you're using a Promise-enabled driver already, use promises.

Comment: **WARNING**: You must use a password-specific hash like [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt). **DO NOT** use a weak, high-speed hash like SHA or MD5.

Comment: **WARNING**: Use placeholder values every time, not just intermittently. You've injected `'${message.author.id}'` in your query which is a potential injection vulnerability. Tip: Don't use template strings for queries, avoid the temptation to interpolate.

Comment: You probably hit an error condition and/or dropped the ball somewhere along your callback chain. It's really not easy to say as this code is quite involved.